# doble zero at the first of integer not showed in xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, excel, ms-office

i create a XML file using PHP and MYSQL .
When i open XML file in notepad++ the content like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <item>
        <price>26000</price>
        <value>278</value>
        <code>00101189</code>
    </item>
    <item>
        <price>17000</price>
        <value>92</value>
        <code>00101100</code>
    </item>
    <item>
        <price>119000</price>
        <value>112</value>
        <code>7228687815233</code>
    </item>
    <item>
        <price>48000</price>
        <value>400</value>
        <code>6954851217411</code>
    </item>
</products>
```

But when open this file in Microsoft Excel 2013 the content like this :

[image]

As you see at The second row in code column , code should be " 00101189 " but output is " 101189 " .

What is problem ? my XML file or Microsoft excel ?

Comment: a number do not have leading Zeros. Format it as a string

Comment: You could have a look at [creating a schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa468557.aspx) for your XML file - but it's simpler to just format that column as text in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel will automatically hide leading zeroes. Try opening in a text editor and hopefully everything will be intact!

Comment: i guess it's my problem , but for this for stock managing i wanna be sure
, thank you so much